# why my pod's status don't have condition with type is readiness gate?

Tags: kubernetes

I use pod readiness gate on kubernetes-1.12.6，like this
https://v1-12.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-readiness-gate

but it does not work like the document

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    run: tomcat
  name: tomcat
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: tomcat
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: tomcat
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: tomcat
        name: tomcat
      readinessGates:
      - conditionType: www.example.com/feature-1
      restartPolicy: Always
```

I want to have a pod with status like this

```
Kind: Pod
...
spec:
  readinessGates:
    - conditionType: "www.example.com/feature-1"
status:
  conditions:
    - type: Ready  # this is a builtin PodCondition
      status: "True"
      lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: 2018-01-01T00:00:00Z
    - type: "www.example.com/feature-1"   # an extra PodCondition
      status: "False"
      lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: 2018-01-01T00:00:00Z
  containerStatuses:
    - containerID: docker://abcd...
      ready: true
...
```

but my pod's status is this

```
status:
  conditions:
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2019-04-27T14:59:00Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Initialized
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2019-04-27T14:59:00Z"
    message: corresponding condition of pod readiness gate "www.example.com/feature-1"
      does not exist.
    reason: ReadinessGatesNotReady
    status: "False"
    type: Ready
```

why?

Answer (score 1):

As per [readinessGates description](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/blob/master/keps/sig-network/0007-pod-ready%2B%2B.md) it seems that some logic external to pod must update this status field. It is up to user to implement such logic.

> After pod creation, each feature is responsible for keeping its custom
>   pod condition in sync as long as its ReadinessGate exists in the
>   PodSpec. This can be achieved by running k8s controller to sync
>   conditions on relevant pods.

Comment: yes，I have seen it.

but, I think it shoud have the condition with name of "www.example.com/feature-1" and status is "False", then my external program can set it to "True" by my logic.

is it?